# Excel vba: Sum values for an account number and enter total on all rows for that account

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like this:

```
   Acct number     Transaction     
   XXXXXX5030      11.33
   XXXXXX5030      37.53
   XXXXXX5030      101.30
   XXXXXX1133      20.33
   XXXXXX1133      21.21
```

I need code that will loop through and find all the accounts with the same number and all all the transactions. Then it would create a new column with the total on each row for that transaction. Like this:

```
   Acct number     Transaction   Total  
   XXXXXX5030      11.33         150.16
   XXXXXX5030      37.53         150.16
   XXXXXX5030      101.30        150.16
   XXXXXX1133      20.33         41.54
   XXXXXX1133      21.21         41.54
```

I have tried using sumif, but it doesn't work. It returns #VALUE! for all cells. My code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Create_CSV").Range("A8").Select ' 
  ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Dim ActN As String
        ActN = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4)

        Dim TotalAmm
        TotalAmm = Application.SumIf(Range("B8:B1000"), Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4), "=ActN")

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TotalAmm



  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need that as VBA? it's a simple formula

Answer (score 2):

Your VBA is an unneeded overkill. Simply use [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b).

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$100, $A2, $B$2:$B$100)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SumIf formula in excel to do this. If your account number is in Column A and the Transactions in Column B you would put this formula in Column C and drag down.

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$10,$A$1:$A$10,A2)
```

My example only assumed there was a range of 10

Comment: Other than using `SUMIFS` (not needed here...), is that any different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do it in vba because it is a huge spreadsheet that is doing many other things... and I want to be able to run it all at once. You all put me on the right path. For the vba, the following worked:

```
TotalAmm = Application.SumIf(Range("A8:A1000"), ActiveCell.Value, Range("B8:B1000"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this line by line:

```
Range("C8:C" & Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row).formula = "Sumif(A$8:$A$1000,A8,B$8:B$1000)
Application.calculate
Range("C8:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).copy
Range("C8:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).pastespecial xlPasteValues
```

Populate the formula to column C in one go (it auto updates the reference automatically)

calculate

Copy the cells

Paste as values

You will find this a LOT quicker than looping the cells.

This code replaces ALL of this:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Dim ActN As String
    ActN = Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4)

    Dim TotalAmm
    TotalAmm = Application.SumIf(Range("B8:B1000"), Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4), "=ActN")

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TotalAmm



ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

This works on what you posted as your solution, I might point out this is different to your original post where your original is trying to sum only on the last 4 charts of the acc no, if you need this post back, we can just create a temp helper column for the formula, do the formula, copy and paste as values then delete the helper column